# Is there an algebraic invariant for complex curves that's mapped to injectively?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, category-theory, riemann-surfaces

Consider the functor $\pi_1: \text{Closed Surfaces} \rightarrow \textbf{Grp}$. This is homotopy invariant; every closed topological surface has a unique fundamental group. In the reverse direction, by classification, if two closed surfaces have isomorphic fundamental group, then the surfaces themselves are homeomorphic. This fails if we move up to $3$-manifolds, and fails spectacularly for dimension $\geq 4$. So I'll restrict my questions to small dimensions.

Question: is there a functor $\text{Complex Curves} \rightarrow \textbf{Grp}$ that has the same properties as before? (In this case, it should be conformally invariant, but the preimages of a given group should be conformally equivalent.) I doubt it, if only because there are continuum many complex structures on a torus, and it seems unlikely that something which can be continuously varied like this will give me a nice algebraic invariant that can differentiate these structures. Bonus question: if this is provably false, is it provably false for rings as well? (Feel free to let rings have unity or not and morphisms take unity to unity or not.)

**Edit**: Zhen Lin noted in the comments below that the Yoneda embedding to **PreSheaf** works fine. I've restricted now to groups and rings. I want there to be no algebraic invariant in the spirit of, say, homotopy groups or the cohomology ring or the group of line bundles that does the job for us.

Comment: If you let the target be a category of presheaves, then you can even achieve a fully faithful embedding...

Comment: @ZhenLin Is the idea just to "cheat" and send every complex curve to its sheaf of holomorphic functions? (I don't see the necessity of the pre- if this is the idea.) The spirit of what I'm thinking of is, say, the fundamental group functor, or going to the group of line bundles or cohomology ring or something similar. I grant that my question is somewhat unclear and I apologize (should I add the `soft-question` tag?)

Comment: You could do that, but I was thinking of the Yoneda embedding.

Comment: Well, for tori there is such an answer (not to group, but even better)--map it to its orbit in $\mathfrak{h}/\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. I don't know of any complete isomorphism invariant group which is attached to complex curves. There are obviously lots of non-injective things which get you there (e.g. Picard group).

Comment: Or, for tori, even better, the $j$-invariant :)

Comment: The integral/rational cohomology ring of a compact complex curve is finitely generated, so there are only countably many isomorphism types of those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a closed Riemann surface $\Sigma$ of genus $g>0$ there is naturally  associated a pair $(\Lambda, H)$, where $H$ is a $g$-dimensional complex vector space and $\Lambda\subset H$ is a full rank lattice (an abelian subgroup isomprphic to $\mathbb Z^{2g}$).

For $H$ you can take $H^1_{DR}(\Sigma; \mathbb R)$ (the degree 1 DeRham cohomology of $\Sigma$ with real coefficients). This is a $2g$-dimensional real vector space, if you just consider the differential structure on $\Sigma$. The complex structure on $\Sigma$ gives $H$ the structure of a complex vector space of dimension $g$. For $\Lambda\subset H$ you can take the  cohomology classes with integer "periods" (=integrals along oriented closed curves in $\Sigma$).

Another natural definition of $H$ is the space of holomorphic 1-forms on $\Sigma$ (but it is then less obvious why it is a $g$-dimensional complex vector space).

If $f:\Sigma\to\Sigma'$ is a conformal diffeomorphism, then the induced map $f^*:H^1_{DR}(\Sigma';\mathbb R)\to H^1_{DR}(\Sigma;\mathbb R)$ is a complex linear isomorphism such that $f^*(\Lambda_{\Sigma'})= \Lambda_{\Sigma}.$

It follows  that the map $[\Sigma]\mapsto [(\Lambda,H)]$ is well-defined (the brackets idicate equivalence classes with respect to the obvious equivalence relations).

The map $[\Sigma]\mapsto [(\Lambda, H)]$ is injective (a complete invariant), but for $g>1$ it is not surjective. The image is an open subset of the set of all equivalence classes of pairs $(\Lambda, H)$, given by the so-called Riemann bilinear relations.

Reference: Griffith-Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: +1: this is the "correct" answer. Let me just comment that the standard name for this object is the _Jacobian_ of the curve.

Comment: Almost. The Jacobian is the complex variety (topologicaly a torus) $H^*/\Lambda^*$, where $H^*$ is the dual vector space of $H$ and $\Lambda^*\subset H^*$ is the dual lattice. The subject is obviously very classical and rich, perhaps the richest and deepest in all of math,  full of names and equivalent definitions. Obviously I cannot hope to summerize it  in several paragraphs. I tried to give a  self-contained formulation  the closest in spirit to the OP question.

Comment: Dear Gil Bor: oops, I was too quick with my previous comment.  Thanks for the correction. By the way, I should add that I wasn't criticising in any way, just adding a bit of jargon that interested readers might like to search for.

Comment: @Asal: On the conrtrary, your comment is quite valuable. As I said, the subject is replete  with so many concepts and equivalent definitions, many given in "coordinates", that it is quite hard to interconnect them into  a geometrically "invariant" picture. I hope other readers add their own concepts like you did (e.g. the period map $\Sigma\to J_\Sigma=H^*/\Lambda^*$).

Comment: This is a far more pleasant answer than I was expecting. I guess I should stop putting off reading G&H.